# Stored Queries in access vs. Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

Is it correct to say that the Functionality of "**stored queries**" in MS access is the same with "**stored Procedure**" in MS SQL Server.
Which one improve the Performance more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an Access query is much more limited than a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). The stored procedure may be better if you are working with an SQL Server back-end and want to do something complicated.

Comment: That means, Stored Procedure improve the performance of my App if I use this?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have a table linked to your Access front-end and all you want to do is select some records, I doubt if a stored procedure will be faster, though I have not tested. Note also that the main use of a table is with forms, so you will always be using Access queries if you work in the way that Access is intended to work since 2007.

Comment: This is your second question about speed problems. Switching to SQL Server Express is not a magic answer if your app is running slowly. You should be able to get it to work quite fast in a simple MS Access set-up, otherwise the problem is elsewhere and SQL Server Express will not fix it.

Comment: It also likely a good point here that the database engine for Access 2010 (ACE) does in fact now allow one to write table level code. This new ability is true engine level table triggers and true engine level store procedure code. In fact this code will run without Access having been installed and if you open the table via ODBC from VB6, FoxPro, vb.net etc. and update a row, then these table triggers and store procedure code will run. So while the create-procedure DDL sql command just creates a select statement, the new Access database engine does in fact support real store procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

A Sub or Function in a module is probably closer to a stored procedure than a query. You can:

- Execute one or more sql statements.
- use flow-control and other logic
- interact with objects outside of the database: files, email, execute programs etc.
- execute/use other sub routines and functions

A query has similarities to a view (except a view can't accept paramters and only executes a select statement), but is more like a table user-defined function (Without some of the flow control).